# How do I insert data into database from url

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

This is my url link and device return corresponding value in browser body. Now I insert this data into my database table name `IpRelay`. First I explode my device return data. Then I am trying to insert exploded data.

Here is my code. But it doesn't work.

```
public function get_data(){
    $contents = file_get_contents('http://10.5.40.83');
    function multiexplode ($delimiters,$string) {
        $ready = str_replace($delimiters, $delimiters[0], $string);
        $launch = explode($delimiters[0], $ready);
        return  $launch;
    }
    $get_device_data = multiexplode(array(",",":",), $contents);

    $this->IpRelay->create();
    $this->IpRelay->set($this->request->data['get_device_data']);
    $save = $this->IpRelay->save();
    echo $save ? "I've created the link" : "Error creating link!";
    die($this->IpRelay->id);
}
```

I am new in cakephp and I am using cake version 2.7.5.
Would you help me please.

```
url=> http://10.5.40.83/ 
device return value=> 10,5,40,83:0,11,0,0,556
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->IpRelay->create();
$this->IpRelay->set($this->request->data['get_device_data']);
$save = $this->IpRelay->save();
echo $save ? "I've created the link" : "Error creating link!";
die($this->IpRelay->id);
```

Instead of above code I am using below this code and it works properly

```
$this->IpRelay->read(null, 1);
$this->IpRelay->set(array(
    'a'     => $get_device_data[0],
    'b'     => $get_device_data[1],
    'c'     => $get_device_data[2],
    'd'     => $get_device_data[3],
    'e'     => $get_device_data[4],
    'f'     => $get_device_data[5],
    'g'     => $get_device_data[6],
    'h'     => $get_device_data[7],
    'volt'  => $get_device_data[8]
));
$this->IpRelay->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope it is easier and helpful for your

```
$this->Model_name->read(null, 1);
$this->Model_name->set(
    array(
        'field_1'     => $get_device_data[0],
        'field_2'     => $get_device_data[1]
    )
);

$this->Model_name->save();
```